# How to control existing Custom Properties that are assigned to armatures via operator?

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, armature, operator

I'm creating an addon that sets the Blender settings based on what type of render we need. However, I'm unable to change the attributes that control aspects of the rigs. I can't access them. The thing must be done by operator so one is capable of just pressing a button and setting the preset settings for Viewport, Light or Final Render.

```
def execute(self, context):
    # Simplyfy config
    if bpy.context.scene.render.use_simplify == True:
        bpy.context.scene.render.use_simplify = False
    
    # Curves Config
    bpy.context.scene.render.hair_type = 'STRIP'
    bpy.context.scene.render.hair_subdiv = 3

    # CP Config
    bone_name = "c_pos"
    for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        if obj.type == 'ARMATURE' and bone_name in obj.pose.bones:
            c_pos_bone = obj.pose.bones[bone_name]
            for prop in c_pos_bone.keys():
                if prop.startswith("001-CantidadPelo"):
                    prop.value(1.0)
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Does anyone have any clue or way to access those properties?